# Move boolean list in Excel to new cells

Tags: google-sheets, boolean

I have a list of several hundred items in Excel. Each item has a numerical value. I am doing a boolean check on each item -- whether it's value is below 500,000,000 or not. I want to avoid VBA. (I'm in Google Sheets.)

Approximately one fifth of my items will meet the boolean criteria. The question is how do I take all of those results and move them into a new list that excludes the false boolean results so that I can then do calculations on those items only.

So for example, cells B2-B500 have numerical values, cells C3-C500 does a boolean and I want to have cells G2-GX display those values that returned `true` in a concatenated list (no empty cells).

Solution: so if anyone comes across this issue use the pivot table filter:

https://googlesystem.blogspot.ca/2011/05/pivot-tables-in-google-spreadsheets.html#gsc.tab=0

Comment: how about filtering on true and copy paste?

Comment: Need to avoid copy and pasting, it's for my boss' use and he's too lazy/tech illiterate to do anything. Has to be completely automated.

Comment: Hey thanks for your help, pivot tables are definitely the way to go here.

Answer (score 1):

Try Query instead:

**G2:**

```
 =QUERY (A:F, "Select * where B<500000000 and B is not null")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd try:

```
=filter(B2:B,B2:B<500000000)
```